# How to prove $\int_0^t W_s^2dWs = \frac{1}{3}W_s^3 - \int_0^t W_s ds$ using Ito's formula?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Please help me with this problem.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user hasn't shown that they've done any work to solve the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As @SRKX suggested, full answers are provided below.

(a). Using Ito's lemma
\begin{align*}
d\left(W_t^3\right) &= 3W_t^2 dW_t +3W_t dt.
\end{align*}
Integrating on both sides, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
W_t^3 = 3\int_0^t W_s^2 dW_s +3\int_0^t W_s ds.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t W_s^2 dW_s = \frac{1}{3}W_t^3 -\int_0^t W_s ds.
\end{align*}

(b). Note that 
\begin{align*}
df(t, W_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_t} dW_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_t^2} dt.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
dX_t &=-\frac{1}{(t+W_t)^2}dt -\frac{1}{(t+W_t)^2}dW_t +\frac{1}{(t+W_t)^3}dt\\
&=(-X_t^2+X_t^3)dt -X_t^2 dW_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: If you decide to answer to this, then I'd invite you to provide the full solution.

Comment: I thought to give him some hint, and leave the remaining to himself.

Comment: I totally understand, but then these should actually be embedded as comments. The idea is that we're trying to have questions/answers on the site, rather than questions/hints which might be more suited to a forum-like site. I mean he's accepted your answer but I thought it would be better now to completely solve it (it's not that long anyway).